# Robot Obstacle Recording/Avoiding

Tags: java, while-loop, robotics

I'm trying to make this robot go in random directions until it reaches an obstacle. Then it should record that obstacle (Obstacle = 1,2,3 etc) and switch direction. This should go on until the timer expires.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    Robot therobot = new Robot();

    int x = 10000;
    int obstacles = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r1 = rand.nextInt(255) + 1;
    int r2 = rand.nextInt(255) + 1;

    therobot.setWheelVelocities(100,100);
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - before < x){
        Thread.sleep(x);
        if( therobot.isObstacle() ==true || therobot.isTapped() == true)
        {
            r1 = rand.nextInt(255) - 255;
            r2 = rand.nextInt(255) - 255;
            obstacles = obstacles++;

            therobot.setWheelVelocities(r1, r2);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(obstacles);

    therobot.stopWheels();
    therobot.quit();
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It just goes until the timer expires but it won't stop or record anything.

What am I missing ?

Comment: i'd suggest not using 10secs for each iteration when testing... also we can't help you if we don't know what the behavior is for isObstacle and isTapped. Also why do you call therobot.quit() at the end of the while loop? shouldn't that be called when you are out of the while loop? just guessing based on the name

Comment: the isObstacle returns true if either left or right obstacle sensor detect an obstacle. Same thing for the isTapped, if something touches it, it should stop moving. also, they're boolean.

Comment: what does therobot.quit() and stopWheels()?

Comment: Exactly what it says on the tin. stopwheels will stop the wheels from moving, therefore the robot. therobot.quit will  properly closes the connection with the robot and resets the robot so that it is immediately ready to be controlled by subsequent programs.

Comment: Is your position being updated in another thread? Because you are asking this thread to do nothing for 10 seconds and check obstacles once at the end.

Comment: This is everything I have.. No other things linked to it. You just confused me even more now Tanmay.

Comment: You must have declared `therobot` variable somewhere

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't write it down here.

Comment: Could you please post the constructor of robot class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

```
int x = 10000;
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - before < x){
    Thread.sleep(x);
    // Processing
}
```

The first iteration of while loop takes entire time duration of 10 seconds because of `Thread.sleep(10000)`.

Sleep amount should be significantly lesser than total duration.

Comment: True, I moved those outside the loop. problem is still there.

Comment: THAT WAS IT ! It works now . I just took out the Thread.sleep(x) for good. It does what I wanted it to do now. Thanks bud !

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Comment: Completely removing `sleep` may shoot up your CPU usage because of tight loop.